# How do I know which processors are physical cores?

Tags: cpu

I've got an Intel i7 2700k here, and I'd like to know how I can tell which processors are physical and which are virtual (ie: hyperthreading). I'm currently running a Conky script to display my CPU temps, frequencies, and loads, but I'm not sure that I've done it right:

[image: awesome]

I've written my own script to get temperatures and frequencies from `i7z`, but these only correspond to physical cores. I'm currently displaying each core like this:

```
${cpu cpu1} ${lua display_temp 0} ${lua display_load 0}
${cpu cpu2}
${cpu cpu3} ${lua display_temp 1} ${lua display_load 1}
${cpu cpu4}
# ...
```

I'm not sure that this is right, because of the loads and temperatures I see sometimes. In `/proc/cpuinfo`, how are cores sorted? First all physical then all virtual? Each physical core then its virtual core(s)? How are they sorted?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can know about each processor core by examining each cpuinfo entry:

```
processor       : 0
[...]
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0

processor       : 1
[...]
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 2 

processor       : 2
[...]
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 4 

processor       : 3
[...]
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 3
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 6

processor       : 4
[...]
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 1

[and so on]
```

`physical id` shows the identifier of the processor. Unless you have a multiprocessor setup (having two separate, physical processor in a machine), it will always be 0.

`siblings` show the number of processor attached to the same physical processor.

`core id` show the identifier of the current core, out to a total of `cpu cores`. You can use this information to correlate which virtual processor goes into a single core.

`apicid` (and `original apicid`) show the number of the (virtual) processor, as given by the bios.

Note that there 8 siblings and 4 cores, so there is 2 virtual processor per core. There is no distinction between "virtual" or "real" in hyperthreading. But using this information you can associate which processors are from the same core.

Answer (score 18):

you can also use lscpu:

```
# lscpu --all --extended
CPU NODE SOCKET CORE L1d:L1i:L2:L3:L4 ONLINE MAXMHZ    MINMHZ
0   0    0      0    0:0:0:0:0        yes    3200.0000 800.0000
1   0    0      1    1:1:1:0:0        yes    3200.0000 800.0000
2   0    0      2    2:2:2:0:0        yes    3200.0000 800.0000
3   0    0      3    3:3:3:0:0        yes    3200.0000 800.0000
4   0    0      0    0:0:0:0:0        yes    3200.0000 800.0000
5   0    0      1    1:1:1:0:0        yes    3200.0000 800.0000
6   0    0      2    2:2:2:0:0        yes    3200.0000 800.0000
7   0    0      3    3:3:3:0:0        yes    3200.0000 800.0000
```

here logical cores 0 and 4 go to core 0

Answer (score 5):

The `/sys` filesystem holds a nice overview of this information. Here is an example from an SMP quadcore box with Hyperthreading:

```
# grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{,1}?/topology/thread_siblings | tr : \\t | sed 's,^,    ,'
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/topology/thread_siblings   00000000,00000101
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/topology/thread_siblings   00000000,00000202
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/topology/thread_siblings   00000000,00000404
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/topology/thread_siblings   00000000,00000808
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/topology/thread_siblings   00000000,00001010
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/topology/thread_siblings   00000000,00002020
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/topology/thread_siblings   00000000,00004040
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/topology/thread_siblings   00000000,00008080
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/topology/thread_siblings   00000000,00000101
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/topology/thread_siblings   00000000,00000202
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/topology/thread_siblings  00000000,00000404
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/topology/thread_siblings  00000000,00000808
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/topology/thread_siblings  00000000,00001010
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/topology/thread_siblings  00000000,00002020
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/topology/thread_siblings  00000000,00004040
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/topology/thread_siblings  00000000,00008080
```

Identical content denotes threads of the same core. I.e.

- cpu0 / cpu8
- cpu1 / cpu9
- etc.

There is similar information in the `core_siblings` pseudo-file, along with yet more topology information.

Answer (score 3):

If you see the '`ht`' flag in `/proc/cpuinfo` then you have hyper-threading enabled and each real core is split into multiple threads, there is no concept of real thread and virtual thread: both are effectively virtual.

What you may wish to investigate is comparing cores and sockets, use the '`physical id`' topology identifier to group cores together.

Comment: The `ht` flag only indicates that multi-threading (HTT) is supported by the CPU -- not if it's enabled or not. Even then, it can't always be relied upon, e.g., it falsely indicates that an i5 i5-6500 supports HTT: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88184/intel-core-i5-6500-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-60-ghz.html

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer is very interesting.

After some googling, I found some related subjects:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/235825/disable-hyperthreading-from-within-linux-no-access-to-bios
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274585/linux-find-out-hyper-threaded-core-id
- [Checking if HyperThreading is enabled or not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33450/checking-if-hyperthreading-is-enabled-or-not)

On the last link, the python script does not work when your host have many physical IDs. I tried to modify it with a different condition at the end :

Changing:

```
if p > 0:
```

to

```
if p % 2 == 1:
```

But it does not work as expected, based on the previous message. By the way, you can do something more comprehensive than:

```
grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{,1}?/topology/thread_siblings | tr : \\\t | sed -r 's,^,\s\s\s\s,'
```

with:

```
for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-9]*/topology/thread_siblings_list; do echo -n "$file "; cat $file; done |sort -k2 -n
```

[...]

What is interesting on a many cores host with hyperthreading enable is the distribution of logical cores on the hardware.

For instance, on one of my computer (48 logical core, 2 physical processors, 24 (12*2) 'real cores' (so, also 24 virtual cores)) :

```
for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-9]*/topology/thread_siblings_list; do echo -n "$file "; cat $file; done |sort -k2 -n

 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/topology/thread_siblings_list 0,24
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu24/topology/thread_siblings_list 0,24
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/topology/thread_siblings_list 1,25
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu25/topology/thread_siblings_list 1,25
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu26/topology/thread_siblings_list 2,26
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/topology/thread_siblings_list 2,26
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu27/topology/thread_siblings_list 3,27
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/topology/thread_siblings_list 3,27
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu28/topology/thread_siblings_list 4,28
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/topology/thread_siblings_list 4,28
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu29/topology/thread_siblings_list 5,29
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/topology/thread_siblings_list 5,29
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu30/topology/thread_siblings_list 6,30
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/topology/thread_siblings_list 6,30
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu31/topology/thread_siblings_list 7,31
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/topology/thread_siblings_list 7,31
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu32/topology/thread_siblings_list 8,32
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu8/topology/thread_siblings_list 8,32
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu33/topology/thread_siblings_list 9,33
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu9/topology/thread_siblings_list 9,33
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu10/topology/thread_siblings_list 10,34
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu34/topology/thread_siblings_list 10,34
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu11/topology/thread_siblings_list 11,35
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu35/topology/thread_siblings_list 11,35
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu12/topology/thread_siblings_list 12,36
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu36/topology/thread_siblings_list 12,36
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu13/topology/thread_siblings_list 13,37
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu37/topology/thread_siblings_list 13,37
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu14/topology/thread_siblings_list 14,38
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu38/topology/thread_siblings_list 14,38
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/topology/thread_siblings_list 15,39
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu39/topology/thread_siblings_list 15,39
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu16/topology/thread_siblings_list 16,40
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu40/topology/thread_siblings_list 16,40
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu17/topology/thread_siblings_list 17,41
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu41/topology/thread_siblings_list 17,41
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu18/topology/thread_siblings_list 18,42
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu42/topology/thread_siblings_list 18,42
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu19/topology/thread_siblings_list 19,43
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu43/topology/thread_siblings_list 19,43
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu20/topology/thread_siblings_list 20,44
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu44/topology/thread_siblings_list 20,44
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu21/topology/thread_siblings_list 21,45
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu45/topology/thread_siblings_list 21,45
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu22/topology/thread_siblings_list 22,46
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu46/topology/thread_siblings_list 22,46
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu23/topology/thread_siblings_list 23,47
 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu47/topology/thread_siblings_list 23,47
```

It means cpu0 and cpu24 share the same physical hardware "address".
Same thing for cpu1 and cpu25...

So, basically, if I would like to disable hyperthreading from the my linux OS, I should put '0' in cpu{24..47}/online with

```
for fake_cpu in {24..47}; do echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$fake_cpu/online;done
```

You will notice how interesting my system is numbering the cores.

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of quotes for things on the terminal; it is far simpler to read.