# Disable Intel Alder Lake efficiency cores on Linux

Tags: linux, intel

My application requires maximum single-thread performance and suffers from switching to the Intel E cores.

I am looking for a way to disable E cores on Intel i9-12900K on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine without access to bios (it is a rented dedicated server). Or for any possible way to distinguish such cores and assign CPU affinities using `taskset` to exclude them from execution.

Tried to find the answer myself in Google. Only found that there are indeed scheduler issues for now, but there is no clear fixes or workarounds available for my problem.

Comment: Stupid brute-force workaround: run some test program once for each core, locked to that one core. Any differences between them should show up in the results, and then you can use that to set the cpu affinity for good.

Comment: @ilkkachu I've just did this right when you commented. I run 7z benchmark on one thread for each core and used taskset: `taskset -c CORE_ID 7z b -mmt1`. Now I know that the last 8 cores are efficiency cores, they have 20-25% less MIPS. But I think that it is not very elegant solution and there may be some people who know more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`taskset` is a standard feature to assign cores to applications which works perfectly in your situation. E.g. in the case of Intel Core i9 12900K pin your task to the first sixteen cores and you're good to go:

```
taskset 0xFFFF application
taskset -c 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 application
```

The second form is longer but easier to read.

AFAIK the standard Linux kernel doesn't currently have any infrastructure to hint the kernel that certain applications need to use certain types of cores. Yes, the Linux kernel supports BIG.little ARM architectures but I've not heard of API to utilize this feature.

As of January, 2022 the Linux kernel does **not** support Intel Thread Director in any shape or form. There have been no patches, nothing.

Lastly, it's worth noting that Linux and Windows differ in how they report HT/SMT siblings.

Windows lists them in pairs, i.e. Core 1: Thread 1 Thread 2, Core 2: Thread 1 Thread 2, etc. Linux first lists all physical cores, then their HT/SMT siblings.

So, if you want to test physical cores **without** using HT/SMT for a sixteen-core CPU, you'll do this:

```
taskset -c 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 application
taskset 0xFF application
```

More on it here: [How do I know which processors are physical cores?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57920/how-do-i-know-which-processors-are-physical-cores)

---

Option N2: you can put E cores offline, and they will become invisible for your system:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{NN}/online
```

For Intel Core i9 12900K that'll be

```
for i in {16..23}; do echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu${i}/online; done
```

Comment: Linux 5.18 added some [support for teaching the scheduler about metrics provided by the hardware](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Intel-HFI-For-Linux-5.18) that are relevant to Alder Lake, though there's [more ongoing work](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Intel-Linux-Classes-Of-Tasks-TD) that probably won't arrive until Linux 6.2 or later. The system may now be able to schedule your workload acceptably on its own if you're using a new enough kernel.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of disabling e-cores entirely, use [`isolcpus`](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017747) boot parameter to isolate e-cores from the general scheduler.

For example, in case of Intel Core i9 12900K:

`$ sudo vi /etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="isolcpus=16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23"
```

`$ sudo update-grub`

You can then still use e-cores by manually assigning them to specific processes using `taskset` or `cset`:

`$ sudo taskset -p 0xFF0000 <pid>`

Alternatively, can also use [`cset shield`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/cset-shield.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `chcpu -d [cpulist]` to bring cores offline at any time.

See `man chcpu`