# How to tell if the CPU supports hyper threading

Tags: cpu, intel, hyperthreading

I know it should be a simple matter of `grep -wl ht /proc/cpuinfo` but that's not always accurate.

I have an i5-7440HQ CPU which doesn't support hyper-threading ([Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/97459/Intel-Core-i5-7440HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz), [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaby_Lake#Mobile_processors), and my BIOS agree on this).

Yet `/proc/cpuinfo` and `dmidecode` both show that hyperthreading is supported (but disabled).  Kernel 4.10.8

When running a report of all machines that are HT capable, but have it disabled, this machine shows as a false positive... I'd like to fix that.

Is there a more accurate test that will show that this CPU really doesn't have HT?

**Edit:**

The related question [Checking if HyperThreading is enabled or not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33450/checking-if-hyperthreading-is-enabled-or-not) asks how to tell if it's *enabled*, which is not what I'm asking.  Some of the answers to that question mistakenly attempt to answer this question instead, but none of them provide a correct answer (as noted above).

Comment: The annoying thing about the latter linked question is that the accepted answer is wrong (although it does point to a correct, if sub-optimal, answer). :-(

Comment: @StephenKitt that's really a different question. When hyperthreading is disabled, it could be because it's turned off in BIOS or because the CPU doesn't support it. The way to check if it's supported (my question) is different than the check to see if it's enabled (the other question).

Comment: The odd thing here is that `/proc/cpuinfo` is pretty much a 1-1 representation of the information provided by the *CPU itself* with the `CPUID` instruction. How does the BIOS know that HT isn’t supported, if the CPU claims it is? Curious...

Comment: @StephenKitt exactly, it's very odd, that's why I wanted to ask the question.

Comment: What does `cpuid | grep hyper-threading` output? (Using [`cpuid`](http://www.etallen.com/cpuid.html) which is probably packaged for your distribution.)

Comment: @StephenKitt reports: `hyper-threading / multi-core supported = true`

Comment: That means your CPU claims to support hyper-threading (`cpuid` just reports the results of the `CPUID` instruction). What does `lscpu | grep " per "` report? Do you have any other 7440HQs to test against?

Comment: @StephenKitt `Thread(s) per core:    1`, but that's really just saying that hyperthreading isn't currently turned on, right?  No, I don't have any other 7440HQs (too new), but it's likely that more will show up in the office in the coming months.